# Can't get component data initialization with prop value to work

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass an array as prop to a child component to use it there localy.The main idea would be to be able to edit this array in child component and then pass it to php via axios.
When i try to initialize the childs local data with the prop i get an empty array as data.

parent component

```js
<template>
 <stocare-comanda v-if="isStocareComandaActive == true" :comanda="comanda" :id="id"></stocare-comanda>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data: function() {
    return {
      lista: [],
      comanda: [],
      id: "",
      isStocareComandaActive: "false"
    };
  },
methods:{
 stocare: function() {
      this.id = event.currentTarget.id;
      this.isStocareComandaActive = true;
      axios
        .post("../stocare/deschide_comanda", { id: this.id })
        .then(response => {
          this.comanda = response.data.data;
          // console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
};
</script>
```

child component

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: ["id", "comanda"],

  data: function() {
    return {
      cmd: this.comanda
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {

  }
};
</script>
```

Expected result:
In my child component, cmd should get the array from comanda prop.

Actual result:

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVbT6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is merely speculation but I am guessing during the initialization of your child component, this.comanda in your parent component is empty, and thus it initializes cmd with empty array.

try  setting

```
 mounted(){

   this.cmd = this.comanda 
 }
```

if this doesn't work it means you are changing comanda variable in your parent so

```
return{
  cmd: this.comanda
}
```

doesn't work, because this only sets cmd in the first initialization of the variable.

Comment: You are right,i added: ````v-if="comanda != ''"```` in the tag for the child component and this prevents it from mounting before comanda gets the array.Thanks!